# Does anyone know of any WPF based web browsers?

Tags: browser, wpf

Once I have heard of a browser being developed WPF. But it was just in the early stage of development. Can anyone remember the name with the link?

N.B. Don't know whether this is the right place for this question. If someone thinks that some other StackExchange site better suits this question, please suggest.

Comment: This is an appropriate place. It's a question about a desktop application (even if it is a browser).

Comment: @ChrisF I was in doubt because I think the question is more appropriate for the developers than power-users.

Comment: I think if you asked it on Stack Overflow (unless you were after the source) it would get closed fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it Chrome based?

http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/wpf-chromium-webbrowser-source-code/